# Populate a RecyclerView in a bottom nav fragment from firebase realtime database

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I want to populate a recycler view with a realtime firebase database query. The recycler´s fragment is on a bottom nav (the second destiny). The layout:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_id_owner_menu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_menu_owner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_id_owner_menu"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_add_item_menu"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/add_item"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_item"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/rv_menu_owner"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

In my gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.7.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.3.1"
// ViewModel Kotlin support
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1"
//Koin
implementation "org.koin:koin-android:2.0.1"
implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-viewmodel:2.0.1"
//Navigation
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
```

The code in fragment:

class MenuOwnerFragment : Fragment() {

```
private var _binding: FragmentMenuOwnerBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!
private val firebaseOwnerViewModel: FirebaseOwnerViewModel by inject()
lateinit var ownersMenuDb: DatabaseReference
private lateinit var menuRecyclerView: RecyclerView
private lateinit var firebaseRecyclerAdapter: FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MenuOwner, MenusViewHolder>

private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)

override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
): View? {

    _binding = FragmentMenuOwnerBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    firebaseOwnerViewModel.currentOwnerLD.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
      binding.tvIdOwnerMenu.text = it.id

    })
    val ownerId = binding.tvIdOwnerMenu.text.toString()

    menuRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_menu_owner)
    menuRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())


    loadFirebaseData(ownerId)

    binding.btnAddItemMenu.setOnClickListener { view ->
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_navigation_menu_owner_to_itemMenuFragment)
    }
}

private fun loadFirebaseData(ownerId: String) {

    ownersMenuDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Menus").child(ownerId)

    firebaseRecyclerAdapter = object : FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MenuOwner, MenusViewHolder>(

            MenuOwner::class.java,
            R.layout.menu_row,
            MenusViewHolder::class.java,
            ownersMenuDb
    ) {
        override fun populateViewHolder(viewHolder: MenusViewHolder?, model: MenuOwner?, p2: Int) {

            viewHolder?.binding?.itemName?.text = model?.itemName
            viewHolder?.binding?.itemDescription?.text = model?.itemDescription
            viewHolder?.binding?.itemPrice?.text = model?.itemPrice.toString()
            Glide.with(requireContext()).load(model?.itemPhoto).into(viewHolder!!.binding.itemImage)
        }
    }
    menuRecyclerView.adapter = firebaseRecyclerAdapter
}

class MenusViewHolder(mview: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(mview) {
    val binding = MenuRowBinding.bind(mview)
}
```

}

It works and compiles and if I put .child("a value from my firestore child") instead of .child(ownerId), the result it´s what I expect.
With .child(ownerId), the textView shows the right value in the app, but the recycler shows "null". Debuger said "val ownerId = binding.tvIdOwnerMenu.text.toString()" is "". I don´t know what I´m missing because this way:

```
    firebaseOwnerViewModel.currentOwnerLD.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
      binding.tvIdOwnerMenu.text = it.id
    })
```

of passing parameters works fine for me in other fragments/activities. I´d try with sinthetics (instead of view binding), findViewById, coroutines (to delay loadFirebaseData(ownerId)), all the compile ways with/without parameter ownerId, the code onCreateView, onViewCreated, the FIFA, the UEFA... It´s my first post, sorry if I´m not clear. Any suggestion?  Thanks in advance

Comment: So what exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: Hi,  Alex Mamo and thanks for your interest. When I click the menu nav bar of this fragment, pass the parameter (ownerId) through the viewModel, the text view show the correct value but: val ownerId = binding.tvIdOwnerMenu.text.toString() value it´s "" (debuging) and the recycler view shows "null" in the right corner and nothing more. I solved the problem with navigation safe args and calling the fragment out of the nav bar, but I´m very intrigued why don´t cach the right value and shows "" because I use this same lines of code, view model and livedata in the other nav fragment and works fine